# How can I read a 2D file which content is not separated by spaces in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I have a matrix stored in a file (number.txt), like this:

```
12323456  
54254311  
76534522
```

How can I read such matrix in Fortran, so the result would be:

```
1 2 3 2 3 4 5 6  
5 4 2 5 4 3 1 1  
7 6 5 3 4 5 2 2
```

It is very easy to separate these columns using awk and read it in Fortran. But, I would like to know if I can do all this using only Fortran. After I am done with I will need to multiple this matrix by its transpose.

Comment: This is not a how to program site so this question really is not appropriate here so I vote to close. However, one idea is to read in each line into a character variable and access each character using a start and ending index (similar to arrays). Example: `read(42,*) MyLine` MyLine(1:1) would contain the character '1'.

Comment: *This is not a how to program site so this question really is not appropriate here so I vote to close. However,*  @DanSp. make your mind up, voting to close and answering the question in a comment is a sure way to convince newcomers that this *is* a site to have this kind of question answered.

Answer (score 1):

Fortran formatted input and output is based on *fields*.  Fields are not required to be separated by spaces.  Here you may consider the data `12323456` to be a single field of width 8 or 8 fields of width 1 (or other combinations).

If you want to read a value from a integer field of width 1, the format item `I1` will allow that value to be read.  If you have eight integer fields of width 1 next to each other `8I1` will allow reading of those.

```
implicit none
character(8) :: input(3)=['12323456','54254311','76534522']
integer i, values(8)

do i=1,3
  read(input(i),'(8I1)') values
  print '(8(I1,:,1X))', values
end do

end
```

Comment: As the number of integer fields is stored in a variable I just needed to create a format string: write(form, "(A,I0,A)") "(", ncols, "I1)". Thank you.