# How to obtain the smallest figure out of five figures using OO Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran95

In what way can I get the smallest figure in a given five digit figure. E.g `23764`. How do I get `2` being the smallest.

Taking the figure as a digit such as `456879`, in order to obtain the smallest from the digit which is `4`, I implemented the following

```
program findsmallestFigure
implicit none
integer:: figure
integer:: c,smallest,largest

   smallest = 9
   largest = 0
   figure = 23456

 do while(figure .GT. 0 )  
   c = MOD(figure,10)
   largest = max(c,largest)
   smallest = min(c,smallest)
   figure = figure/10
 end do

  print *,'The smallest digit is',smallest
end
```

How do I achieve the same result using Object Oriented approach in Fortran ?

Comment: What is a figure? How is it defined in your code? Is it an integer number? Is it a character. Show your code, ir is completely necessary. Please do read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: There are several ways to do this, so please explain how you would like to do this and where you struggle. One particular way would be to create an array with [each element corresponding to a digit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55481924/3157076), then find the minimum.  You attempt, as with the previous comment, should be shown so that we don't have to write an entire program.

Comment: I have an answer already, wish I could add the answer.

Comment: Can you explain why and how you want to apply the Object-Orientated programming model to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a module with a user-defined type that contains all the results, and the subroutines to fill in the values

```
module numstat

    ! Holds the statistics of a figure
    type stat
        integer :: smallest, largest, count
    end type

    ! Constructor from a figure. Invoke by 'stat(1234)`
    interface stat
        module procedure :: calc_stat
    end interface

    contains

    ! Fill statistics type from a figure
    function calc_stat(fig) result(s)
    integer, intent(in) :: fig
    type(stat) :: s
    integer :: digit, f
        ! make a copy of the figure because intent(in) arguments
        ! are immutable (cannot change).
        f = fig 
        s%smallest = 9
        s%largest = 0
        s%count = 0

        do while(f > 0 )
            s%count = s%count + 1
            digit = mod(f, 10)
            s%largest = max(s%largest, digit)
            s%smallest = min(s%smallest, digit)
            f = f/10
        end do

    end function

end module
```

Then use the module in the main program

```
program SONumstat
use numstat
implicit none    
type(stat) :: s
integer :: figure

figure = 23456

s = stat(figure)

print *,'The number of digits is ', s%count
print *,'The smallest digit is ',s%smallest
print *,'The largest digit is ',s%largest

end program SONumstat
```